# fetching the markers but lat & lng being null - vue.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to display markers on the map. I fetched the data without a problem seeing in vue dev tool. Also `this.markers` has the data as well. But inside my `lat` and `lng`  is null

I am not sure the way I am doing is wrong?

```
data(){
        return {
            markers: []

        }
    },
    computed: {
        articles(){
            return this.$store.getters.getArticles;
        }
    },
    watch: {
        articles(){
            this.buildMarkers();
            this.clearMarkers();
        }
    },
    methods: {
        clearMarkers(){
            for( var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++ ){
                this.markers[i].setMap( null );
            }
        },
        buildMarkers: function(){

            this.markers = [];

            for( var i = 0; i < this.articles.length; i++ ){

                var position = new google.maps.LatLng(this.articles[i].lat, this.articles[i].lng);
                console.log(position);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: position,
                    map: this.map
                });

                this.markers.push(marker);
            }
        },
    },
    mounted(){
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('article-map'), {
            center: {lat: this.latitude, lng: this.longitude},
            zoom: this.zoom
        });
        this.clearMarkers();
        this.buildMarkers();
    },
```

to make it more understandable this is the image of the devtool.

[image]

By the way I can see the map. Only problem is I can't see the markers on it because lat & lng being empty.

Comment: Syntax looks bad to me. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: IN your articles watcher shouldn't you be clearing then building your markers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of markers, therefor the `buildMarkers()` function must have been executed, which would have added them to the map.

The map property of the marker opened up in the console has been set to null (removing it from the map), this implies that `clearMarkers()` has also executed.

I notice in your articles() watcher you first build then clear your markers. I think it should possibly read

```
articles(){
  this.clearMarkers();
  this.buildMarkers();
}
```